# iOS run on Apple Silicon - Mail to open file is NOT placed in "Documents/Inbox"

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, apple-silicon

From Apple's iOS development document:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html

So in native IOS environment, when I used Mail to open some file attachment and chose my iOS app to open it, I can find the file copied to "Documents/Inbox" directory.

But when I run iOS in Apple Silicon - the same above scenario, the file is NOT copied to "Documents/Inbox". In fact, there is no "Inbox" sub-directory under "Documents".

Does anyone know where the file copied to?

Answer (score 0):

Got answer from Apple Developer Forum:

"From your app delegate's [application:openURL:options:] method, you can NSLog the [url path]."

Getting the original file path from [url path] and then copy to "Documents" which now I can manipulate this mail attachment file. So have to do this and cannot hard code the file path: "Documents/InBox" which only work reliably in iOS device..